# How to log errors with Sentry when offline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sentry

So my app is supposed to work offline as well as online. So how do I get errors in my Sentry dashboard when a user is offline?

Comment: For future reference, the Offline integration has been deprecated in favor of Transports for browser based SDKs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/transports/

Answer (score 2):

Sentry provides an [offline caching transport](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/transports/#offline-caching). Sample usage from a browser-based application:

```js
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://...",
  transport: Sentry.makeBrowserOfflineTransport(Sentry.makeFetchTransport)
  transportOptions: {
    // Caching options, e.g. maxQueueSize.
  }
})
```

From the documentation:

> To enable offline events caching, use makeBrowserOfflineTransport to wrap existing transports and queue events using the browsers' IndexedDB storage. Once your application comes back online, all events will be sent together.
>
> Offline caching is not supported in IE due to a lack of IndexedDB features.

Comment: Thanks for [documenting](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/integrations/plugin/#offline) it!

Answer (score 1):

While they're offline you obviously can't send any data to Sentry server but you can, for example, store those errors in LocalStorage until a user gets online again. And when they are online send these errors to Sentry.